# Way to have control over what data type I pass into my tables using C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using code-first entity framework to create tables in a SQL database from objects. I'd like to have control over what types my variables are once they are in the SQL table.

For example, I have a table with a CountryName column. Currently, it has the data type nvarchar(MAX). I'd like for the data type to be nvarchar(40) to save memory.

I can do this manually in SSMS, but it'll take me a few hours to do this for all my tables. I'm looking for a way to do this in code.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I also want control whether or not my data type can accept NULL. So, I want to change all my data types (e.g., int, nvarchar, DateTime) to not accept NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DataAnnotations to configure your model. To set the length to 40 you would apply the attribute MaxLength to a property.

```
[MaxLength(40)]
```

Or, as your question asks to do this in code you override the `OnModelCreating` in your DbContext and use the Fluent API to configure your model.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //Configure domain classes using modelBuilder here

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .Property(p => p.CountryName)
                .HasMaxLength(40);
}
```

Walk through all the pages in the following tutorial to learn all the different ways to configure properties in your mode.http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of [DataAnnotations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/dataannotation-in-code-first.aspx) in general, in order to specify things like this. Specifically, in the case you mentioned you need to make use of the attribute called [MaxLength](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/maxlength-minlength-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx):

```
[MaxLength(40)]
public string CountryName { get; set; }
```